# Show $\sum_{n=1}^∞ \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}=\ln(2)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Taylor's theorem

a) If $x∈{0,1}$ and $n∈ℕ$, show that $$
    \begin{vmatrix}
    ln(1+x)-(x-\frac{x^{2}}{2}+\frac{x^{3}}{3}+...+(-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^{n}}{n}) \\
    \end{vmatrix}<\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}
$$

b)Using the result of part "a" to Show $\sum_{n=1}^∞ \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}=\ln(2)$
Note: If $(-1)^{0}=1$

I already proved part a, but I do not know how to do part b although I know it is simpler than a. If your could help me, I'll thank you

Comment: By the way, write **\ln** to generate $\ln$ for $\ln(2)$ :)

Comment: $|\ln (2)-\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}k|<\frac{1}{n}$

Answer (score 0):

One can check the convergence of the series by the alternating series test.  Abel's theorem then tells us that the value is continuous from the left, meaning the value is $\ln(1 + 1)$.

Comment: The radius of convergence is $1$. So $x=1$ is on the boundary of the interval of convergence. You can't just "plug in" boundary values - a power series may or may not converge on the boundary.

Comment: Ah, you're right.  It looks like this is a consequence of Abel's theorem then.

Comment: I was about to post an answer mentioning Abel's theorem, when I noticed it's not needed. Part (a) gives an explicit bound for the error if $0<x<1$; if you let $x\to1$ in part a you get the inequality in W. mu's comment, qed. (No problem letting $x\to1$ in part a because everything there is a continuous function of $x$.)